# How to convert Columns to rows in Spark scala or spark sql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have the Data like this.

```
+------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col1_cnt | Col2_cnt | Col3_cnt | Col1_wts | Col2_wts | Col3_wts |
+------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| AAA  | VVVV | SSSS |        3 |        4 |        5 |      0.5 |      0.4 |      0.6 |
| BBB  | BBBB | TTTT |        3 |        4 |        5 |      0.5 |      0.4 |      0.6 |
| CCC  | DDDD | YYYY |        3 |        4 |        5 |      0.5 |      0.4 |      0.6 |
+------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have tried but I am not getting any help here.

```
val df = Seq(("G",Some(4),2,None),("H",None,4,Some(5))).toDF("A","X","Y", "Z")
```

I want the output in the form of below table

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
| Cols_name | Col_cnt | Col_wts |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| Col1      |       3 |     0.5 |
| Col2      |       4 |     0.4 |
| Col3      |       5 |     0.6 |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Admin: Can you get me this question answered

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general approach for transposing a DataFrame:

1. For each of the pivot columns (say `c1`, `c2`, `c3`), combine the column name and associated value columns into a `struct` (e.g. `struct(lit(c1), c1_cnt, c1_wts)`)
2. Put all these `struct`-typed columns into an array which is then `explode`-ed into rows of `struct` columns
3. Group by the pivot column name to aggregate the associated `struct` elements

The following sample code has been generalized to handle an arbitrary list of columns to be transposed:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("AAA", "VVVV", "SSSS", 3, 4, 5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6),
  ("BBB", "BBBB", "TTTT", 3, 4, 5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6),
  ("CCC", "DDDD", "YYYY", 3, 4, 5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c1_cnt", "c2_cnt", "c3_cnt", "c1_wts", "c2_wts", "c3_wts")

val pivotCols = Seq("c1", "c2", "c3")

val valueColSfx = Seq("_cnt", "_wts")

val arrStructs = pivotCols.map{ c => struct(
    Seq(lit(c).as("_pvt")) ++
      valueColSfx.map((c, _)).map{ case (p, s) => col(p + s).as(s) }: _*
  ).as(c + "_struct")
}

val valueColAgg = valueColSfx.map(s => first($"struct_col.$s").as(s + "_first"))

df.
  select(array(arrStructs: _*).as("arr_structs")).
  withColumn("struct_col", explode($"arr_structs")).
  groupBy($"struct_col._pvt").agg(valueColAgg.head, valueColAgg.tail: _*).
  show
// +----+----------+----------+
// |_pvt|_cnt_first|_wts_first|
// +----+----------+----------+
// |  c1|         3|       0.5|
// |  c3|         5|       0.6|
// |  c2|         4|       0.4|
// +----+----------+----------+
```

Note that function `first` is used in the above example, but it could be any other aggregate function (e.g. `avg`, `max`, `collect_list`) depending on the specific business requirement.

Comment: Perfect.Thank you so much @Leo C :-)